# buscar resultado de consulta sql en array php

Tags: php

me encuentro con el siguiente problema:
tengo un array llamado `$data2` y al realizar una consulta `sql` el resultado del mismo poder buscarlo en el array, estoy trabajando con `checkbox` por lo cual si el resultado de la consulta `sql` se encuentra en el array `$data2` este imprima un `checked`. Este es el código que estoy trabajando:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
 // CADENA DE TEXTO A COMPARAR
 $nombre_ids = $row[2].','.$row[1].','.$row[0];
 // CICLO APRA RECORRER EL ARRAY  
 for($i=0;$i<count($data2);$i++){ 
  // COMPARAR SI EXISTE LA CADENA SQL EN EL ARRAY  
  if($data2[$i]==$nombre_ids){
   $mensaje .= '            
   <tr style="background-color:#FF7575;">
    <td>
     <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="'.$row[0].'" id="'.$nombre_ids.'" checked>  
     <label for="'.$nombre_ids.'">'.$row[2].'</label>   
    </td>
   </tr>';
  } else{
   $mensaje .= ' 
   <tr>
    <td>
     <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="'.$row[0].'" id="'.$nombre_ids.'">  
     <label for="'.$nombre_ids.'">'.$row[2].'</label>   
    </td>
   </tr>'; 
  } 
 }
}
```

El problema es que me duplica los datos de la consulta dependiendo de cuantos datos tenga en el array `$data2`  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues resulta que hay una función en PHP que se llama `in_array` para verificar si una cadena de texto existe en un array. Por lo que lo solucioné de la siguiente manera:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
 $nombre_ids = $row[2].','.$row[1].','.$row[0];
 // ESTA FUNCIÓN ES LA QUE BUSCA LA CADENA DE LA CONSULTA SQL EN EL ARRAY   
 if (in_array($nombre_ids, $data2)) {
  $mensaje .= '            
  <tr style="background-color:#FF7575;">
   <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="'.$row[0].'" id="'.$nombre_ids.'" checked>  
    <label for="'.$nombre_ids.'">'.$row[2].'</label>   
   </td>';
 } else{
  $mensaje .= ' 
  <tr>
   <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="'.$row[0].'" id="'.$nombre_ids.'">  
    <label for="'.$nombre_ids.'">'.$row[2].'</label>   
   </td>'; 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Todavía puedes simplificar el código, ahorrándote por los menos seis líneas. Dado que la cadena que concatenas en `$mensaje` es casi la misma, puedes asignar a variables los valores que serían diferentes dentro del `if`, y luego haces la concatenación una sola vez, al salir del `if`:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $nombre_ids = $row[2].','.$row[1].','.$row[0];

    /*
        *Declaramos las variables vacías
        *sólo adquieren datos si se cumple el if
    */
    $cssFondo='';
    $attrChecked='';

    if (in_array($nombre_ids, $data2)) {
         $cssFondo='style="background-color:#FF7575;"';
         $attrChecked='checked';
     }

    /*Concatenamos usando las variables*/
    $mensaje.='<tr '.$cssFondo.'>'.
                '<td>'.
                    '<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="'.$row[0].'" id="'.$nombre_ids.'" '.$attrChecked.'>'.  
                    '<label for="'.$nombre_ids.'">'.$row[2].'</label>'.   
                '</td>';
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, debería trabajar en eso de simplificar código lo tomaré en cuenta la próxima vez (Y).